# Yii2 - I edit the actionDelete() in my controller for my needs but it just ignores the code just delete the GridVIew data

Tags: gridview, controller, yii2

I tried to edit `actionDelete()` in my controller. What I plan is when I delete a record in my GridView, it would also access and edit my database.

Here is my actionDelete():

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $accounts = new Accounts();
    $accounts_id = $model->accounts_account_id;
    $accounts = Accounts::findOne($accounts_id);
    $oldDebit = $model->debit;
    $oldCredit = $model->credit;
    $accounts->amount = $accounts->amount-$oldDebit;
    $accounts->amount = $accounts->amount+$oldCredit;

    $this->findModel($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

So when I delete the record on the GridView, I plan to simultaneously access my database and edit some values. But what happens is that it ignores the code and just deletes the record. Is there something I don't know that is special about the `actionDelete()` function?

Comment: Where have you called the save/update function in your code?

Comment: It's in the same controller.

Comment: Oh my! You are good! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot `$accounts->save();`

Thanks @Chinmay